# Adding double quotes to a paragraph with CSS

Tags: html, css

Lets say I have this paragraph:

```
<p class="myclass">This is my paragraph</p>
```

What is the CSS code to add double quotes to this paragraph? (So it will render "This is my paragraph")

```
.myclass {}
```

Comment: To give the quote some context, you may want to consider using a blockquote and then styling it using pseudo-elements as suggested.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use **[pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Pseudo-elements)**:

```
p.myclass:before, p.myclass:after {
    content: '"';
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2bE8j/1/**

Answer (score 173):

Actually, the accepted answer is wrong, or at least suboptimal. It should be:

```
q { quotes: '\201c' '\201d'; }
q:before { content: open-quote; }
q:after  { content: close-quote; }
```

The `\201c` here is Unicode for a left curly double quote. There's no reason you could not write the double quotes directly in the rule for `q`:

```
q { quotes: '“' '”'}
```

`open-quote` and `close-quote` are special values for the `content` property, which refer to the strings given as values for the `quotes` property.

Now you can just say:

```
<p><q>This is my paragraph</q></p>
```

Or some variant thereof; you could of course add the `before` and `after` rules directly on `p` if you would prefer:

```
body { quotes: '\201c' '\201d'; }
p:before { content: open-quote; }
p:after  { content: close-quote; }
```

This permits you to factor out the specific characters used for quotes using the `quotes` property, without changing all the `before` and `after` rules. For instance, you can then do things such as

```
:lang(de) { quotes: "»" "«"; }
```

to get German-style quotes, if the `lang` attribute has been set to `de` on any ancestor.

The `quotes` property actually allows you to specify additional sets of quotes, for use with nested quotes. See the docs for more details.

```css
body { quotes: '\201c' '\201d'; }
q:before { content: open-quote; }
q:after  { content: close-quote; }

:lang(de) { quotes: "»" "«"; }
```

```html
<p>Quoth the raven, <q>Never more.</q></p>

<p lang="de">Sprach der Rabe: <q>Nie du Tor.</q></p>
```

References:

- [`quotes` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/quotes)
- [`:lang` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang)
- [`content` property, with `open-quote` and `close-quote` values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content)
- [`q` element for quoted strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/q)

Comment: It's disappointing that this answer doesn't have more upvotes... :(

Comment: this worked fine for me with the exact style I wanted to

Comment: I had no idea about the `lang` pseudo or that you could set quote characters for elements or that there are keywords for open/close-quote.  So this answer is awesome and much more complete than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 89):

```
.myclass:before
{
content: '\201C';
}

.myclass:after
{
content: '\201D';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Here is what I did to make the quotations on my blockquote work.

This is for the first quotation mark:

```
blockquote:before{content: open-quote;}
```

and this is for the second quotation mark:

```
blockquote:after{content: close-quote;)
```

However, this only works in CSS3.