# CSS content for double quote doesn't work

Tags: css

I tried `'>\0147'` but it doesn't seem to work, is it the right syntax ?

```
.blockquote p::before {
    content: '>\0147';
    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

Comment: `0147` isn't a quote. what quote are you going for? a standard double quote hex is `22` so you would use `content: '\22';`

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040217/adding-double-quotes-to-a-paragraph-with-css

Comment: `>` shouldn't be in the content property at all. And `\0147` is the [letter N with a caron](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/letters/).

Comment: @MichaelCoker thanks I read an article which says 0147 was a double quote :) thanks for \22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

CSS:

```
.blockquote p::before {
content: open-quote;
font-family: serif;
font-size: 3em;
line-height: 0;
display: inline;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="blockquote">
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```